# Android seems to be overriding my Messnger Lite app

Tags: notifications, files

I am not tech savvy so am hoping someone can help and in a way I can understand. I was trying to free up some space on my phone and moved a bunch of files on my phone to the SD card I have in it. Since doing that I cannot control the notification sound for my Messenger Lite app I have installed. When I get a message and receive the popup notification on my phone from that app, the little popup box with still say Messenger Lite at the top, but instead of seeing the little icon associated with that app, it shows the Android robot symbol. I am just hoping by including that bit of info it will help pinpoint the issue. The best way to describe it is that Android is overriding that app. It won't let me set any custom sound for the app, not even ones that came preinstalled on my phone. I know I somehow combined files or must have somehow overwritten a file when transferring them to my SD card. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Messenger Lite app, but that didn't fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I would assume that the Android robot symbol is a place holder which is displayed if the original icon can not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. Notify icon is a robot, but I can change the sound of notification. What's is your android ROM? My is lineage os 16

For notify sound change I am using this Google app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.soundpicker